# Efficient data structure for associating data with filesystem paths?

Tags: c#, data-structures, dictionary, path, trie

I need to keep some data in memory about a possibly large number of files and directories (typically up to a few hundreds of thousands). The obvious approach is to use a `Dictionary<string, Something>` with the path as the key, but there are two problems with this:

- many of the files will have a large part of their path in common, so it's probably a waste of memory to store the full path of each file
- I need to be able to quickly access the data about all the descendants of a directory; with a dictionary, the only way to do this is to test each key and check if it starts with the specified path, which is quite inefficient

This problem seems like a good candidate for using a prefix tree (or [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)), with segments of the path as "characters". I tried to implement it, and the performance is not too bad for lookup by prefix (about 4 times faster than a dictionary), but it has two issues:

- the memory consumption is not reduced, probably because of the overhead of the list of children for each node
- the construction time is much worse than with a dictionary (about 4 times slower to fill the collection)

I'm sure it must be a very common problem, so perhaps there are well known solutions that I'm not aware of?

Comment: did you look on something like [CloudGraph](http://www.cloudgraph.com/) ?

Comment: @Tigran, thanks, but it doesn't give any specific details about what it can do... Also, it says "The beta-release is currently scheduled for Q1 2012", but it's apparently still in beta; I need it now, and I need it to be robust, so a beta version is not an option.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: yes I know that. That was just a hint(direction) to look on... In *my* opinion it would be hardly possible to have robust graph (and not tree) structure, fast construction and pick perfromance all in once. In some of them you have to "pay" and laverage them to get best result in *current* project. By the way, I'm curios too to listen for others, who have an experience with that in .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few generic ideas:

First, a [Patricia trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) is probably the best-known approach for improving the memory consumption of tries - it compacts paths in which all nodes have a single child into one node, and concatenate the characters along the path. There is also a version in which you look at the data as a sequence of binary digits, which has the advantage that you always have at most 2 child nodes, and it's also easier to implement.

Second, the memory consumption really depends on how you store the children of a given node - do you maintain an array of 256 nodes? That's usually the most efficient way for direct lookup, but also consumes the most memory and is slow if you need to iterate through all the children. Other options are:

- Store an array of pairs `(letter, child node)` - This is probably the most memory efficient, since it only stores the objects you actually care about, and it also has a good performance for iterating through all children. However, you have to check all pairs for direct lookup - which is usually fine farther from the root, but could be a problem near the root.
- Store some kind of dictionary inside each node that maps a letter to a child node. That's the most balanced with respect to performance - it gives you reasonably good speeds for all operations and is somewhat memory efficient.

Also, if you construct the whole collection up-front and then just query it, there is an approach for storing the child links based on [Tarjan tables](ftp://reports.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/78/683/CS-TR-78-683.pdf) that will probably increase the construction time,  but will save memory and query time later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently I'm using linked lists to store child nodes. It's not the most efficient for lookup, but I don't expect to have too many nodes at each level (a few dozens in a typical folder structure), and it's very efficient for insertion. The radix tree is an interesting optimization, but in my case it doesn't apply, because I need a distinct node for each level along the path. Tarjan tables seem a bit complex for my taste...

Comment: There is an additional optimization that can be applied - combine this answer with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph

Comment: Yes, a DAWG might decrease the memory usage, but it increases the construction time a lot. It depends on the inserted words if it's worth it or not.

Comment: @icepack, thanks for the link. In my case, I'm more concerned about prefix redundancy than suffix redundancy, so it's probably not a very big optimization. Since it's also more complex than a trie to implement, I'm not sure it's worth it...

Answer (score -1):

What about Prefix tree like approach. i.e if you want to store

```
/root/x
/root/a/b
/root/a/c
/root/a/d
/root/a/e
/root/a/c/e
/root/a/c/f
Here is how your tree will look like. 
                       root
                     /    \
                    x   __ a __ 
                       /  / \   \ 
                     b   c    d   e
                        / \
                       e   f
```

It will space efficient as every directory name will be stored only once.
Also search as well as insertion will be O(log(n))

Comment: It's actually a prefix tree, and as mentioned in my question, I already tried it.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Sorry I missed that you already tried prefix tree.